# Attempting to read mongoDB document properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I'm trying to read the property levelenabled from a document stored in my MongoDB database. When I log the returned data to console after finding the document with the GuildID(discord.js) it logs the correct document but when I try to check a value in that data the property I'm checking is undefined. Here is my code:

```
const data = await serverdata.find({ //note serverdata is a reference to the serverdata Schema
        GuildID:message.guild.id
    });
    if(!data) return;
    console.log(data.levelenabled) //the output of this is undefined therefore I can not check the boolean status
```

And yes the function is async

I should also add that yes the property levelenabled exists in the document and when logging the GuildID it also is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `findOne`

```js
await serverdata.findOne(...)
```

Using `find` or `findMany` will return a `cursor`.